# How Can Groupable Kendo UI Grid By Click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use kendo ui grid in mvc  that is groupable.
By default by click and drag be groupable. 
How can i change the default that i can groupable by click on column title or specific link

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [group](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-group) method of the Kendo DataSource to perform grouping. Simply call it to group by certain field:

```
dataSource.group({ field: "Name" });
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/OTEmaQos/1/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot Atanas. i use kendo asp.net mvc server wrapper i want by click on title of my grid grid be groupable(instead of click and drag) . do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, I do have an idea. Did you check my answer and demo?

Comment: my problem was that i didnt know how to got kendo datasource object f in client side and manupulate it

Answer (score -1):

Try this live demo. 
http://jsfiddle.net/4xzj9k8g/

```
group: { field: "team" },
groupable: true,
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation (or background) to the code you have provided. Code only answers are considered low quality.